# onclick event in button

Tags: html, jquery, css

i want to heading in above and icon list content with this each image...its hide and show images with text..
when click each button.button1 shows button1 images with heading and when i click button2 button1 is hide and show button2 images with content in same palce.this is the codinInitial Image Show/Hide CSS

Button Data Attribute
data-showme|IMAGE-ID-NAME
Dynamic Image Hide/Show JS

i want to heading in above and icon list content with this each image...its hide and show images with text..
when click each button.button1 shows button1 images with heading and when i click button2 button1 is hide and show button2 images with content in same palce.this is the codinf

Comment: Please provide some code so that others can understand what you have tried and debug the issue correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Display: none when the button is click see below example for reference.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="button-01" style="display: none"> <button onclick="closebutton1()">button-1</button> </div> <div id="button-02" style="display: none"> <button onclick="closebutton2()">button-1</button> </div>
```

JS Code:

```
function closebutton1(){ document.getElementById('button-02').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('button-01').style.display = 'block'; } function closebutton2(){ document.getElementById('button-02').style.display = ''; document.getElementById('button-01').style.display = 'none'; }
```